# RFC2045-MIME variant of Base 64 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need to convert a encode a string with the RFC2045-MIME variant of base64. However I cant find any options to do this in swift. At the moment i use this method:

```
var str = "\(test1):\(test2)"
str = str.data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)))
```

but this is just the standard base64 encoding not the RFC2045-MIME variant. How can i use the RFC2045-MIME variant?

Comment: How does RFC2045-MIME Base64 differ from what you get? Did you lookup the options at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata.base64encodingoptions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only differences between the base64 encodings specified in RFC 2045 and RFC 4686 are that RFC 2045 specifies a maximum line length of 76 characters, with lines separated by CRNL.

The documentation of `base64EncodedString(options:)` says the default line ending is CRNL, so:

```
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!
let b64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength76Characters)
```

Comment: This did work but i also needed to set the encoding to latin1 so it would accept foreign characters.

Comment: is it possible to distinguish if the base64 your seein is 20145 or 4686?